# Restangular with asp.net web api

Tags: restangular

I was trying to setup basic restangular with ASP.NET Web Api ,

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'restangular'
]);

app.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');
   RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
});

var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('home', ['Restangular', home]);

function home(Restangular) {

   var test= Restangular.all('/HelloWorld');
   alert(test);
}
```

It was not hitting the web api which i have setup
Web api - localhost/api/HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the full URL into setBaseUrl like this:

```
app.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http:/localhost/api');
    RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
});
```

Comment: you certainly don't need the full url if the API is hosted on the same domain. (in this case localhost)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
app.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api/');
});

var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('home', ['Restangular', home]);

function home(Restangular) {

   var test= Restangular.all('HelloWorld').getList();
   alert(test);
}
```